# Split CSV type file in R using strsplit

Tags: r, regex, csv

I am trying to split a string that would eventually be taken out of a CSV file using readLine(). (I know `read.csv()` works better, but the CSV file can have different number of columns for each row. For example, 1st row have 2 column, 2nd row 4 line, 3rd row 2 line.)

Say, the string I am going to parse looks like this:

2011-05-04, "weqr, wrqw", "qweqrw", 12

Eventually, I want it to be split into four parts, meaning I am splitting on commas but only when the comma is outside the quotation marks.

A quick google gives me a JAVA solution which takes advantage of the regular expression `",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"`

But doing something like `a<-strsplit(x,",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")` will generate an error: invalid regular expression.

Comment: I think you just need the `perl=TRUE` option like `strsplit(x,",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", perl=TRUE)`. That regex uses a few advanced regex features that aren't available in the default regex system.

Comment: The question doesn'nt make much sense to me. The read.* function will NOT parse quote-embedded commas as if they were delimiters. This: `read.csv(text='2011-05-04, "weqr, wrqw", "qweqrw", 12', header=FALSE)` returns a 4-column results as desired.

Comment: @Marius, incredible! This works like a magic! Thanks!

Comment: @42, the problem with read.* function is not quote-embedded commas. It's the inconsistent number of columns across all rows (like I mentioned).

Comment: The example you posted delivers what you said you wanted when processed with `read.csv`. So if that not the problem then you need to post a different example that illustrates the problem. (... as _I_ mentioned.)

Comment: `read.csv` can handle variable number of columns per row.

Comment: @42- for the record, my question was about how to parse a string with commas but escape quotes. I merely mentioned CSV to tell the background. This is a valid question even without CSV file. I can read it from an excel file for all that matters.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That was what I did in the first place and read.csv threw an error.